# media queries not working for smartphones

Tags: html, css, size, viewport

This media query seems to work when I resize the viewport window on my browser, but when I launch the site on a smartphone it looks zoomed in. Once I zoom out it looks okay, but when it loads it looks zoomed in...so I can only assume that something isn't breaking correctly.

Here's what I have in my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

And here is the first media query that I have in my CSS: The default body size of the document (when being viewed on a web browser on a computer) is 1200px.

```
@media screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:800px){
body {
width:800px;
}

.container {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background-image:url("img/background.jpg");
}
```

Any ideas as to why this may not be working?

EDIT:

I also have media queries for smaller viewport sizes that I'm adding to my original post. So it should launch on a smartphone, right?

```
@media only screen and (min-width:375px) and (max-width:667){
body {
width:480px;
margin: 0 auto;    
}
.container {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background-image:url("img/background.jpg");
}

#logo {
color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0px;
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing: 6px;
padding-top:110px;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Just curios on what phone are you testing this? Does it have a 320px display or 480px? Care to share?

Comment: it's an iPhone 6 plus. I'm not sure of the dimensions of the top of my head but I think its more than 480... I have also opened it on an iPad and it still seems to launch the desktop version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

instead of your tag.

https://alwaystwisted.com/articles/2013-01-10-dont-do-this-in-responsive-web-development

Comment: This didn't appear to change anything. But good to know though.